# Using an ImageIcon and a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, imageicon

My goal is to have an imageIcon and add it so a JLabel so it will appear on my GUI. So far my code is:

```
package classes;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Picture extends JFrame {

    private ImageIcon _image1;
    private JLabel _mainLabel;      

    public Picture(){           
        _image1 = new ImageIcon("picture1.jpg");
        _mainLabel = new JLabel(_image1);
        add(_mainLabel);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    
}    

package classes;

public class Driver {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Picture p = new Picture();    
    }    
}
```

The problem is the picture does not appear on my GUI. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that Java is looking in the right location for your picture1.jpg file? Is this file located in the current working directory?

Put this code somewhere in your program so that it gets called when the program is run:

```
// show the current working directory
System.out.println("current working directory is: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

The String returned will tell you where Java is looking, where your current working directory is located. You can then use that information to adjust your path or you could always just use the full path to the image file.

**Edit:**
Also, don't forget to pack your JFrame so that it will layout the components and size itself accordingly:

```
   public Picture() {

      _image1 = new ImageIcon(IMAGE);
      _mainLabel = new JLabel(_image1);
      add(_mainLabel);

      pack(); // to tell the layout managers to set up the GUI
      setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center things
      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
```

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate the help man. You helped me fix the problem. It was looking in my project directory. All I needed to do was add "src/classes/" in front of picture1.jpg. Thanks again!

Comment: @Spencer: Glad this helped. If it solved your problem, then please "accept" the answer. Also please look at the edit in my post.

Comment: chances are specifying a name of src/classes/picture1.jpg is not the right thing to do, more likely you want to use `new ImageIcon(Picture.class.getResource("/picture1.jpg"));`

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: yep that's true, especially if there ever is a plan to Jar this baby. Also, I prefer to get my images via the `ImageIO.read(...)` method which for one this gives greater flexibility regarding caching of resources.

Answer (score 0):

For setting image to jlabel simple put one line code in your program :

```
yourlabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("your image location here")));
```

we can set [Jlabel](http://tutorialdata.com/example/swing/JLabelIconExample.html) with image and text also.